# How can I attach cable clips to an outside wall?

Tags: electrical, outdoor

I have plenty of cable clips that work great indoors, but I want to attach a cable to an outside pebbledash wall. The existing cable clips, which have broken, appear to have been nailed into some kind of plug, but I can't see what.

What is a good technique for attaching cables to a wall that won't accept a simple nailed clip?

Comment: I've seen cable clips nailed into the mortar between the bricks: I assume the mortar is softer, so accepts the nails.  But it can be difficult to determine where the mortar is, when it is concealed with pebbledash :(  (That's why I'm writing this as a comment, rather than an answer.)

Answer (score 2):

The original solution turns out to be bits of hardwood doweling inserted into the wall, with the cable clips hammered into them.

Comment: Nice idea... I was wondering about using rawlplugs, but I assume those require screws, so this seems like a neat way to use simple nailed cable clips.  Can you say approx what diameter the holes / doweling are?  And I assume the holes are drilled into the brick, not the mortar?

Comment: The doweling was around half a centimeter diameter, and drilled into the brick. I would suggest finding some doweling first, then drilling slightly smaller holes

Comment: Oh: that's quite thin, then.  Thanks for this :)

Answer (score 0):

I would have said pin plugs are the better solution here. They are basically like small rawlplugs designed to be used with small nails instead of screws. They also have advantage of not eventually rotting like wood.

Here is a picture of them (the pin plug is on the left)
[image: Picture of pin plug and cable clip]